# What does the letter 'S' mean in $S + C = \sin A/2$?

Tags: trigonometry, notation

I recently came across a equation related to multiple and sub-multiple angles which goes like this -

$$S + C = \sin A/2$$
Can someone please help me out with this. According to my knowledge it is just a variable representing something, but I am not satisfied with my understanding.

Comment: Is the equation $S+C=\sin\frac{A}{2}$ (`S+C=\sin\frac{A}{2}`), $S+C=\frac{\sin A}{2}$ (`S+C=\frac{\sin A}{2}`), or $S+C=(1+\sin A)^2$ (`S+C=(1+\sin A)^2`)? (See also [this MathJax guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).)

Comment: This formula in the title doesn't match the formula in the body; which one do you mean? Also, since you only asked about "$S$", does that mean you know what "$C$" means? Finally, information about where you "came across" this equation would be helpful for context; do you have a link or other reference? ([Edit the question](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4140761/edit) to make any clarifications. Comments are easily overlooked and may be hidden.)

Comment: Might the S and C in this context mean angles, i.e. $\angle S + \angle C = \sin A/2$?

Comment: @bjcolby15 I doubt as much. While $A/2$ is angle, $\sin A/2$ is not (insofar as we can distinguish different kinds of dimensionless quantities).